# Hyper-v network issues on initial connection

Tags: networking, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2012

I am running hyper-v on very capable hardware, host is Server 2012r2 and guest is 2008r2. The problem I am seeing is that, when the guest has not had network access attempted in a while or has been rebooted, initial connections fail on the first try then succeed on subsequent retries. For example, if I open a web page to google.com when the server has been sitting idle for a while or even right after a reboot, the page will timeout then when I hit refresh it will load. If I try to establish a RDP session to the gust, it fails on the first try and when I hit the Connect button again, it connects with no problem. The host is running core and the guest is running full GUI. I have one guest and plenty of RAM and cores. I have seen this happening consistently both with and without SR-IOV enabled.

Comment: Have you updated the integration services inside the guest to match the host OS level?

Comment: Can you please add information about how your virtual switch is configured, what kind of physical switch the server is connected to, and whether the VM is using the legacy or new ethernet card?  Also if any VLANs or teaming are in use anywhere.

Comment: I update Integration Services on each guest every time I update the host- so Integration services is up-to-date.

Comment: Here's the switching setup- I have a virtual switch set up as an External network, which is only in use by this VM- at the moment, this is the only VM on the server. The "Allow Management OS to Share" box is also unchecked, and SR-IOV is on (I enabled it when I first ran into this problem to try to give the VM as much control over the network as possible. The network port is plugged in to a Catalyst 2960 @ 100MBit. The VM uses the 4-port Ethernet adapter in the server, specifically port #1. It is an HP DL360 G8, 8 cores, 32GB RAM, and the VM is set to stay within the NUMA node (14000MB)

Comment: Lots of RAM for a single VM, but necessary as it is a terminal server. I have it set to use 8 cores with 100% threshold (To guarantee the VM has 8 full cores). Hyperthreading is enabled. Power management is disabled in the BIOS, and I believe it is disabled on the adapter- still learning Powershell in Core 2012R2. This is a test environment that I am going to turn around into production as soon as I have this issue resolved.